# ckeditor, html5 formular and the form="xxxx" -tag

Tags: html, forms, ckeditor

I would like to integrate ckEditor into an html5-form. The TextArea and the SubmitButton shoud be outside the form-tags.

```
<form **id="myform"** action="example.com"></form>
        <textarea **form="myform"** name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
            This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
        </textarea>
        <script>
            // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
            // instance, using default configuration.
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
        </script>
<input name="clickme" type="submit" form="myform">
```

When I try to send this way, the result freom the textarea is always empty.
Is it possible to place a ckeditor outside the form-tag, even while ckeditor is changing this textarea into a iframe-construction?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right you want to place the checkeditor outside the form. You should be able to place the checkeditor anywhere you want. Once you have the value via javascript you could assign it to a form data value as needed. Here's an example placing the checkeditor somewhere arbitrary, then a form in a arbitrary location, when the form submit is clicked the javascript will update the form value with checkeditor's value and submit the form, here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/edencorbin/c8wassww/9/:

A few key pieces, in the HTML place your checkeditor anywhere:

```
      <textarea class="selector" name="editor1"></textarea>
      <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
      </script>
```

Then you can place your form anywhere, add a hidden field for what the texteditor will be replacing:

```
    <form id="myForm">
       <textarea id="MyTextArea" hidden="hidden" rows="4" cols="50">
       replace this text area input
    </textarea> 
        <a class="btn override" href="#">SUBMIT</a>
    </form>
```

In javascript override your button for form submittal, and first update the field with the value from your checkeditor.

```
    $('.override').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("textarea#MyTextArea").val(CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.getData());
      console.log($("textarea#MyTextArea").val());
      $('#myForm').submit();
    });
```

Comment: Thats it, thanx. Pushing the Content to a hidden field ... was out of my phantasy!!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. If you need more advanced options, look into the jquery adapter. If the answer works for you, could you mark as answered? Thanks.